# Debugging client_side_validations using Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, http-authentication, client-side-validation, sprockets

I am having trouble getting any of it to work. This is my first attempt.  After a while, I did see some change on the page when tabbing out of the password field, but no error message shows up.  Here are the relevant files.  **The idea is to disallow free email domains like aol, yahoo, gmail, etc.** Please help me if you see a bug that's keeping it from working. Thank you so much.

**errors on submit but not in real time–** https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5qUR.png

**[Update]**

```
throw Error("Sprockets::FileNotFound: 
couldn't find file 'public/javascripts/rails.validations.custom.js'\n  
(in /Users/jess/Sites/[appname]/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:10)")
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: { :on => :create }
  #validates :email, presence: { :on => :create }
  validates :email, email_format: true
  has_many :companies
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
[AppName]::Application.routes.draw do
  get "home/index"
  resources :users
  resource :sessions
  root :to => 'users#new'
end
```

**rails.validations.custom**

```
clientSideValidations.validators.local["email_format"] = function(element, options) {
  if (/^.+(@aol\.com)$/i.test(element.val())) {
    return options.message;
  }
}
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require rails.validations
//= require rails.validations.custom
//= require_tree .
```

**en.yml**

```
en:
  errors:
    messages:
      email_format: "is not formatted properly"
```

**User#new**

```
%h2 Sign up

= form_for @user, validate: true do |f|
  - if @user.errors.any?
    .error_messages
      %h3 Form is invalid
      %ul
        - @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
          %li= message
  .field
    = f.label :email
    = f.text_field :email

  .field
    = f.label :password
    = f.password_field :password

  .field
    = f.label :password_confirmation
    = f.password_field :password_confirmation

  .actions= f.submit
```

**client_side_validations.rb**

```
# ClientSideValidations Initializer

require 'client_side_validations/simple_form' if defined?(::SimpleForm)
require 'client_side_validations/formtastic'  if defined?(::Formtastic)

# Uncomment the following block if you want each input field to have the validation messages attached.
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
  unless html_tag =~ /^<label/
    %{<div class="field_with_errors">#{html_tag}<label for="#{instance.send(:tag_id)}" class="message">#{instance.error_message.first}</label></div>}.html_safe
  else
    %{<div class="field_with_errors">#{html_tag}</div>}.html_safe
  end
end
```

**user_spec.rb (all tests pass)**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
  before :all do
    User.delete_all
  end
  describe 'Association' do
    it { should have_many(:companies) }
  end

  describe 'Database Columns' do
    it { should have_db_column(:email).of_type :string }
    it { should have_db_column(:password_digest).of_type :string }
  end

  describe 'Indexed Columns' do
    it { should have_db_index(:email) }
  end

  describe 'Valid Records' do
    user = Factory(:user, email: "foo@example.com", password: 'foobar')
    User.find_by_email(user.email).try(:authenticate, user.password).should == user

    it 'should not allow free email domains' do
      user.email = 'foo@aol.com'
      user.should_not be_valid
    end
  end
end
```

**lib/email_format_validator**

```
class EmailFormatValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(object, attribute, value)
    if value =~ /^.+(@aol\.com)$/i
      object.errors.add(attribute, :email_format, options)
    end
  end
end
```

**application.rb**

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)
require 'rails/all'

Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env) if defined?(Bundler)

module [AppName]
  class Application < Rails::Application

    # TODO perhaps dated // http://mikbe.tk/2011/02/10/blazingly-fast-tests/
    if Rails.env.test? 
      initializer :after => :initialize_dependency_mechanism do 
        ActiveSupport::Dependencies.mechanism = :load 
      end 
    end

    # load lib/
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
    config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]

    config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
    config.encoding = "utf-8"

    # Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]

    # Enable the asset pipeline
    config.assets.enabled = true

    config.generators do |g|
      g.test_framework :rspec, :views => false, :fixture => true
      g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl, :dir => 'spec/factories'
      g.form_builder :simple_form
      g.template_engine :haml
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with haml is `= form_for @user, validate: true` equivalent to the erb version of `<%= form_for @user, :validate => true do |f| %>` i.e. :validate is a hash key with a value of true

Comment: in ruby 1.9, { validate: true } == { :validate => true }

Comment: You should post you solution as an answer, so that you can accept it and close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**domain_validator.js.coffee**

```
invalid_domains = [
"@myway.com",
"@mail.com" ] # two, for example, out of about 1,000

domains_joined = invalid_domains.join('|')
domains_pattern = new RegExp("^.+(#{domains_joined})$", "i")

clientSideValidations.validators.local["email_domain"] = (element, options) ->
  if (domains_pattern.test(element.val())) 
    options.message()
```

**lib/email_domain_validator.rb**

```
   class EmailDomainValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
      INVALID_DOMAINS = %w( 
         @myway.com
         @mail.com ) # two, for example

      def validate_each(object, attribute, value)
        if value =~  /^.+(#{INVALID_DOMAINS.join('|')})$/i
          object.errors.add(attribute, :email_domain, options)
        end
      end
    end
```

I also didn't have the right error message. Now I do (email_domain):

**config/locales/en.yml**

```
en:
  errors:
    messages:
      email_format: "is not formatted properly"
      email_domain: "this email provider is not allowed" # tada!
```